# Is it possible to get the address of the GDT?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdt

I have a bootloader that is setting up the GDT for me. Is it possible to find out the address of this GDT so I can use it?

Comment: In x86 protected mode obviously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just use the [`sgdt`](http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/sgdt.htm) instruction to read out the current setting.

Comment: Wow! I didn't even know that instruction existed! Thank you